Section of étale morphism of algebraic spaces
I am sorry in advance if this question is too naive for specialists. I just realized that I need it when doin research and I haven't taken any serious course on algebraic spaces. Let $u \colon U \longrightarrow X$ be an étale, separated morphism of alebraic spaces. Suppose that $u$ admits a section $s \colon X \longrightarrow U$, then it is similar to schemes that $s$ must be a closed immersion and étale. If we assume furthermore that $U$ is a scheme, then $s$ must be a closed, open immersion.
With schemes, we know that $s$ is an isomorphism onto a connected component of $U$, and $U = \operatorname{Im}(s) \sqcup X$. I am wondering whether we have a same decomposition in case $X$ an algebraic space (where no topological argument can be applied)?

You are asking whether both the image and its complement are both open and closed.  This can be checked after base change to the sets in a locally closed partition of $X$.  Every (quasi-compact) algebraic space has a (finite) partition by locally closed subspaces that are schemes.

You mean that the decomposition can be checked on a locally closed partition of $X$?

Yes, you check over progressively larger open subsets of $X$ that are unions of sets in the partition.
